Shell tabbar цвет выбранной иконки в MAUI
<Shell xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
       xmlns:contentViews="clr-namespace:ManagerHelper.Views.ContentViews"
       BackgroundColor="Transparent"
       TabBarBackgroundColor="White"
       TabBarTitleColor="Black"
       TabBarUnselectedColor="Gray"
       x:Class="ManagerHelper.Views.LobbyShell">
    <TabBar>
        <ShellContent Title="Головна"
                          Icon="home_icon_apple.png"
                          ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate contentViews:BaseInformation}" />
        <ShellContent Title="РЦ"
                      Icon="depot_icon2.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate contentViews:Depots}" />
        <ShellContent Title="Реєстрації"
                      Icon="registrations_list_icon.png"
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate contentViews:ActiveRegistrationsList}" />
    </TabBar>
</Shell>    

Как изменить цвет выбранных значков на панели вкладок? Невыбранные значки я сделал серыми, но не понимаю, как изменить цвет выбранных элементов(сейчас сиреневые).
Пример с цветом по умолчанию (iOS):


Используйте TabBarForegroundColor типа Color, который определяет цвет переднего плана для панели вкладок:
TabBarForegroundColor="Aqua"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:dashboard="clr-namespace:MauiApp.Views.Dashboard"
    xmlns:menu="clr-namespace:MauiApp.Views.Menu"
    xmlns:users="clr-namespace:MauiApp.Views.Users"
    xmlns:about="clr-namespace:MauiApp.Views.About"
    xmlns:auth="clr-namespace:MauiApp.Views.Auth"
    TabBarForegroundColor="Aqua">

    <TabBar>
        <Tab Icon="analysis_primary.svg">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate dashboard:DashboardListPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Icon="menu.svg">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate menu:FlexMenuListPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Icon="user_primary.svg">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate users:UserProfilePage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Icon="about.svg">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate about:AboutPage}" />
        </Tab>
        <Tab Icon="log_out.svg" Appearing="Tab_LogoutAsync">
            <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate auth:LogOutPage}" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>

</Shell>



пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
